# Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed (with Nuxt and Jest)

Tags: travis-ci, jestjs, nuxt.js

For unknown reasons my Jest tests seem to block at the end of my CI via Travis.

The Travis logs say as follow:

> Test Suites: 5 passed, 5 total
> Tests:       31 passed, 31 total
> Snapshots:   0 total
> Time:        21.993s
>
> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
>
> This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

Note that `--detectOpenHandles` does not display anything.

As you can see my tests pass but do not exit, even though I do the following :

```
describe('[INTEGRATION] Index.test.js', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const rootDir = resolve(__dirname, '../..');
    let config = {};
    // ... config

    nuxt = new Nuxt(config);
    new Builder(nuxt).build();
    await nuxt.listen(3000, 'localhost');
    homePage = await nuxt.renderAndGetWindow('http://localhost:3000/');
  }, 30000);

  // This is called after every suite (even during the CI process)
  afterAll(() => {
    nuxt.close();
  });

  // ... my tests
});
```

My tests work fine locally but only do this during the CI process via Travis.

Here is the content of my Jest config file:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'jest-vue-preprocessor',
  },
  setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: './jest.setup.js',
  silent: true,
};
```

With `jest.setup.js` containing `jest.setTimeout(30000);`.

Finally, here is my `.travis.yml` config file:

```
language: 'node_js'
node_js: '8'

cache:
  directories:
    - 'node_modules'

before_script:
  - npm run build
  - npm run lint
  - npm install
  - npm run generate
```

What could be causing this problem? The timeout shouldn't be it as it is needed in order to execute all my integration tests, and I close my `nuxt`session after my integration test suites.

Nothing has majorly been changed between yesterday when it worked and today.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to make sure you wait for the `nuxt.close()` call to resolve.  [It looks like `close` is asynchronous](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/79eb9c80105f737eafa9bd3eb1b5045d12d1d39c/packages/core/src/nuxt.js) and emits a promise that resolves when the connection is actually closed. So Jest probably finishes up before that asynchronous operation finishes. And it's really a timing issue so the CI machine may run things slightly differently causing the `close` call to take longer than it does on your local machine.

Try changing your `afterAll` to something like this:

`afterAll(async () => {
  await nuxt.close();
});`